# __IE_PrintType script error when calling WebBrowser.ShowPrintDialog from windows forms app

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-11

I've been tasked with fixing a bug in a windows forms application written in C# that basically allows the user to perform an operation then print a summary of the results by calling `WebBrowser.ShowPrintDialog()` on button_click. However, upon clicking the Print button, a javascript error is returned, but only in IE10 and IE11; older versions work fine. Unfortunately I'm unable to debug the script error because it causes the app to crash as it attempts to launch IE's debugger.

```
Line: 291
Error: Unable to get property '__IE_PrintType' of undefined or null reference
```

Basically, the results of the user's action are passed through to a browser via WebBrowser.Navigate where they are rendered on the client then can be printed.

```
browser.Navigate(new Uri(targetFile.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute));
```

Unfortunately, I have no clue where this script error is coming from or why. My first inclination was to print out the html output via MessageBox.Show, save it off, then open it directly in IE11 to see if the error reproduced, only to find out that it didn't; IE11 handles it just fine.

Further research led me to believe that compatibility mode is used when using the WebBrowser object, but opening the html in IE11 reveals that it's already using EDGE mode.

What am I missing here?